# Event when A Page in ViewPager goes in Background

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragment-tab-host

I have a view Pager and I want to start an activity when a user leaves the screen with a particular Page open on ViewPager.(either slides to other Page or click any of the Tab host items).I loading a fragment in each Page.

```
int previous=-1;
  mPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position)    
        {
            //Show upgrade pop up if day is greater than free days
            if(previous==selected_week)
            {
               //start activity
            }
            previous=position;
        }
   }
```

But for clicking any other buttons(Tab host ,etc).I am not able get the event.
I tried `onPause()`,`onStop()` and `onDestroyView()` of the fragement(Page) and also the Container.But these events are called when i return to same Tab in Tab host.How can I catch the event for this?.Thanks

Answer (score 0):

When you are using **ViewPager** it's default behavior of viewpager to load it's prev. & next page to make it ready for navigation..

```
@Override
public void setUserVisibleHint(boolean isVisibleToUser) {
    super.setUserVisibleHint(isVisibleToUser);
    if (isVisibleToUser) {
        // View/Page/Fragment is Visible to user on screen
        // Do getView() != null check before doing any UI operation
    } else {
        // View/Page/Fragment is Gone in Background
    }
}
```

Let me know if needed anything..